# Perform customization in edit/add operation using telerik grid using the popup gridmode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, telerik, editing, insertion

I have an application in MVC in which i am using telerik grid to display the record.I am using the entity model for it.
In case of edit and add operation i want to use the popup mode but i am not able to perform any customization:Hiding any column in edit mode,make some column uneditable, showing the proper validation message and maintaing the edit mode ,adding any custom field apart from the database table.

Pleas provide me the way to perform customization in edit/add operation using popup in telerik grid.
Thanks 
Supriya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid is using ASP.NET MVC editor templates for its popup editor form. You can check [this  blog post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html) by Brad Wilson (from the Microsoft ASP.NET MVC team) which shows how to create a custom editor template for your object.